# Provide user to edit zebra color on data table

Tags: interaction-design, interface

Do you guys have some good exemplars to be referred on thinking about how to provide user has the convenience operation on changing zebra color for the data table? The current design is staying on this interface as you can see from the pictures, there are "zebra" and "single" button options. Assume I would like to add the customized color for zebra after you click the plus button, it could come out the color picker window like the second picture. Welcome to discuss together. :D
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to ask-- what's the benefit to the user in being able to change the zebra color?

Comment: For example, like editing the web-report that the report designer will publish it to their customer, the color could be changed to match their client's (company's) main color or logo color and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Too bad I can't comment yet.

Is the term "zebra", something your users know? 
I mainly used the term "alternating" for this purpose.

I can't figure out, why you have 2 colors for single and 3 colors for zebra. 
I'd expect 1 for single, 2 for zebra.
What is the point of clicking "+", do you add a color? What is the value of adding more colors to single? Is it like an easy switcher, so the user doesn't have to handle with the color picker anymore?
How often will a user change colors of the rows?

I'd simplify the interaction. Let the user choose between "zebra" and single and then present her with 2 or 1 color choosing options. On clicking the picker opens and the user selects a color.  For "zebra" use 2 icons where you can clearly see which color you are setting, like the above part, the below part.
remove the "+" because it's confusing.

Comment: There aren't 2/3 colors. There are 2 single color designs (white bg or grey) and 3 zebra palettes (alternating white/grey, or white/blue, or white/green). They are probably default options/variation, so you can easily use the brand colorscheme.